# Como poner un salto de linea en un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero poner un salto de linea en el `div` para que quede

`actualizar 
   datos`

y no `actualizar datos`

pero lo necesito es cuando la pantalla tenga un ancho de `768px` a `1000px`

```html
<button id="btnActualizar" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user iconBoton"></span>
  <div>
    Actualizar Datos
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Intentaste agregar un `<br/>` entre las palabras "Actualizar" y "Datos".

Comment: si pero solo necesito el `<br/>` cuando el ancho de la pantalla este en `768px` a `1000px`

Comment: necesitas utilizar [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Disculpa pase por alto lo del ancho de la pantalla, entonces olvida el `<br/>` e investiga sobre los ***media queries***

Comment: Pero como lo hago con media queries no me pueden dar un ejemplo mas grafico

Comment: Encierralos en un `<span>` y con un `media querie` los pones en `display: block`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algo así necesitas, para ver el resultado dale ver en `pantalla completa`

---

Ref: [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

```css
@media(min-width: 768px){
  .wrap span{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnActualizar" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user iconBoton"></span>
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>Actualizar</span>
    <span>Datos</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Gracias viejo me sirvio mucho